# Events for background processing like Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

Is there a existing way to have Resque return a result after a worker is done processing much like with evented callbacks in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look at resque after_perform hooks for job which will give you indication that job is processed / completed

something like this inside your job

```
class MyJob 
  @queue = :my_job

  def self.perform(*args)
    .... your perform code ...
  end

  def self.after_perform(*args)
    ... Write some code to setup a channel ..
  end 

end
```

This way the `after_perform` hook would be executed after the perform action is `completed/processed` signifying the completion of the job

What I would suggest is to set up a channel(either using `pub/sub` or `list`) between your application and resque job and subscribe/pull that data across to your application where you can identify based on payload that job was completed/processed

Hope this help

Thanks you